# Autocorrect in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans

I was wondering if there is an autocorrect option in netbeans that will correct mistakes such as string into String etc, as I tend to always forget this capitalization.

Tried googling a bit and searching around the options but couldn't find anything.

Comment: not likely, but this is more a question for the netbeans fora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use an AutoHotKey script for that, but I know that's not really what you want

`::string::String` would auto-replace "string" with "String"

AHK Hotstring wiki page [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)
Get AHK [here](https://autohotkey.com/download/)

Comment: This seems like the best solution. Although I think I'll just try getting used to writing lots of Strings..